# How can the assignment from int to object be possible in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

```
class phone {  
    public:  
        phone(int x) { num = x; }
        int number(void) { return num; }
        void number(int x) { num = x; }

    private:
        int num;
};

int main(void)
{
    phone p1(10);

    p1 = 20;    // here!

    return 0;
}
```

Hi, guys

Just I declared a simple class like above one.
After that I assigned int value to the object that class, then it worked!
(I printed its value. It was stored properly)

If there is not a construct with int parameter, a compile error occurred.
So, I think it's related with a constructor. Is that right?

Please give me a good explanation.
Thanks.

Comment: In C++ it is prefered not to put void if there are no parameters. Also you can make your number getting a const function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is legal because C++ interprets any constructor that can be called with a single argument of type `T` as a means of implicitly converting from `T`s to the custom object type.  In your case, the code

```
p1 = 20;
```

is interpreted as

```
p1.operator= (20);
```

Which is, in turn, interpreted as

```
p1.operator= (phone(20));
```

This behavior is really weird, and it's almost certainly not what you wanted.  To disable it, you can mark the constructor `explicit` to disable the implicit conversion:

```
class phone {  
    public:  
        explicit phone(int x) { num = x; }
        int number(void) { return num; }
        void number(int x) { num = x; }

    private:
        int num;
};
```

Now, the constructor won't be considered when doing implicit conversions, and the above code will cause an error.

Comment: I'd add a note to the extent that, while this behavior is "really weird," it is what allows you to write `func(std::string s);` (or `func(const std::string& s)`) and call them as `func("literal");`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz- You're absolutely correct.  By "really weird," I meant "in this context, this is really weird."